# JQ select name shows id

Tags: json, jq

I think this is almost right I'm just missing a piece, if I select `Atlas` I want to display the `Id`

`echo "${json}" |jq '.[] | select(.name=="atlas" | .id)'`

JSON

```
[
  {
    "name": "atlas",
    "id": 2314430,
    "slug": "atlas",
    "description": "",
    "privacy": "closed",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2314430",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2314430/members{/member}",
    "repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2314430/repos",
    "permission": "pull"
  },
  {
    "name": "HAL",
    "id": 2318635,
    "slug": "hal",
    "description": "",
    "privacy": "closed",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2318635",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2318635/members{/member}",
    "repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/2318635/repos",
    "permission": "pull"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the bar on the wrong side

`jq '.[] | select(.name=="atlas") | .id'`

Comment: You don't actually need the bar; `... | select(...).id` will work as well.

Comment: Plus one, great catch i didn't see that @chepner